# Will new local class instance be garbage collected if I return an array it creates?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

Let's say a class instance will build arrays:

```
class FooArrBuilder
{
    public Foo[] FinalResult { get { return arr; } }
    Foo[] arr;
    public void BuildArr();
    ...
}
```

Then it's used like this:

```
Foo[] GetFooArr()
{
    var fb = new FooArrBuilder();
    fb.BuildArr();
    ...
    return fb.FinalResult;
}
```

When an array is built inside an instance local to a function, will the array be moved out of the instance that built it, or will the whole instance be kept in memory just to contain the array? I do not necessarily want to copy the array if the latter is the case - but maybe I could make the class a struct? Help is appreciated :)

If you care to elaborate a bit on C#'s memory model here, it would probably help me to avoid further confusion as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want to learn about [value types and reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4d43ts61.aspx) and also how [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) works.

Comment: Nitpick - it will never be "disposed" because it does not implement `IDisposable`.  The term you're looking for is _garbage collected_.  Even this it would just be _eligible_ for garbage collection - precisely _when_ it's collected is not determinable.

Comment: In short, both your class and the array are reference types. As long as an object is "reachable" i.e. another live object has a reference to it, it too will be kept alive. So as long as you keep references to the array, it will be kept alive. And if you *don't* keep a reference to the object creating the array, it may or may not be collected at some indeterminable point in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The class instance does not "own" or "contain" the array.  It merely references the array, which is allocated on the heap.  Other references to that array will *not* keep instances of that class alive.

If any other objects (or stack frames) refer to that array, the memory on the heap that is allocated for the array will stay allocated for that array.  Once those objects are garbage collected and those stack frames get popped, the garbage collector will claim the memory allocated for that array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be. As long as array items of type `Foo` doesn't hold reference to `FooArrBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now.

When the FooArrBuilder is instantiated, it is done so on the heap.
A pointer to it, the size of an int, is put on the stack.
The reference count to the object allocated on the heap is increased by one.

When the instance of FooArrBuilder creates the array, ALMOST the same process happens for the array; a heap object is once again allocated with reference count 1, this time of type Foo[]. However, this time, no pointer is put on the stack - instead, inside the memory pointed to by the stack pointer we retrieved earlier, the Foo[] arr, which is actually a pointer to a Foo[] object, is set to point to the new array.

When we're about to return, we retrieve another reference to the Foo[], called arr, from the instance. The reference count for the array is now 2.
When the function then returns, the reference to the class instance is lost, and so the reference count is now 0. Therefore the instance is marked as garbage. When the instance is (at some indeterminate point) later garbage collected, the reference it had to the array is lost - and so then the array's reference count is once again 1.

Comment: This is a good play-by-play, but I believe the garbage collector doesn't *count* references.  Garbage collection starts from roots, following references and building a graph of live objects.  If an object is not reachable by this process, it is considered garbage and is reclaimed.

Comment: It's a bit more convoluted (as @JerryFederspiel mentioned). If you *really* want to dig deep into what's going on behind the scene, I'd recommend [CLR via C#](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/book.aspx?id=15528) which has a big chapter about the managed heap and garbage 
collection.